# phpmailer code not working when within function

Tags: phpmailer, php

I have the code below in a function.. however it never adds the attachment to the email. The email comes through fine but with no attachment.

However, if i remove the code from the function and add to it a separate file (without the function part) and in the same directory it works fine.

Why is it not adding the attachment when in a function?

```
function resendOrder()
{
    //global $siteEmailFrom, $siteEmailName, $dir;
    require_once('OrderMailer/class.phpmailer.php');// need this to send email

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    // Now you only need to add the necessary stuff

    // HTML body

    $body = "Testing";

    // And the absolute required configurations for sending HTML with attachement
    $mail->From      = "mark@******.co.uk"; 
    $mail->AddAddress("mark@******.co.uk", "My-webpage Website");
    $mail->Subject = "test for phpmailer-3";
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->AddAttachment("ploxy.jpg");

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "There was an error sending the message";
        exit;
    }
    else{
        echo "Message was sent successfully";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to the name of the attachment "ploxy.jpg", that is: You can't refer to the name of the file.

You have to refer to the temporary filename, you can do something like

```
$_FILES['ploxy']['tmp_name']; // temp_name can be anything
```

Ore more precisely:

```
$filePath = "../images/"; // Path to image, can be the empty string.
$ploxy = $_FILES['ploxy']['tmp_name'];
$mail->AddAttachment($filePath, $ploxy);
```

Basically: You must upload your file to the script before you can send it; http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Ok thanks.

SHould that not be:

$filePath = "../images/"; // Path to image, can be the empty string.

$ploxy = $_FILES['ploxy.jpg']['tmp_name'];

$mail->AddAttachment($filePath, $ploxy);

Comment: No, the file extension should not be there.

Comment: Remember to vote up if It's helpful and accept if it solves your problem. If it doesn't then I can tell you that this has been solved many times if you just google it correctly.